# How to integrate Azure media player in android

Tags: android, video-streaming, azure-media-services

I have a manifest streaming url which I have to play. How can I integrate azure media player in android to play the streaming video?

Comment: Are you trying to integrate playback into android native app or into web based application which will be used on android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found another work around to play manifest url. By just concatenate 
`"(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)"`  at the end of the url, you can play this url with any video player.

Comment: Hi @code_geek -  Are you using Azure media player for playing the streaming url? Or any other player library.

Answer (score 2):

Please check http://mingfeiy.com/android-hls-playback-via-azure-media-services .
blog post "Shows you how to generate Http Live Streaming (HLS) version 3 via Azure Media Services, which is a new feature we recently added, in order to support HLS playback in a wider range of Android devices".

You can also use Android Native SDK to playback the HLS steam.

Comment: Hi @George, The URL is not working. Its saying - "Account Suspended"