# Azure Media Services Flutter Video play issue

Tags: flutter, azure-media-services, flutter-video-player

My Question already asked by someone but did not answered can someone help me with this

Here is the link :

[Azure Media Services Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58844066/azure-media-services-flutter)

I got same issue while try to play this URL.

https://amssamples.streaming.mediaservices.windows.net/3b970ae0-39d5-44bd-b3a3-3136143d6435/AzureMediaServicesPromo.ism/manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Newest

After tested, I believe it's flutter's problem.It is recommended to submit an issue on github and let the official fix it.

**It has nothing to do with azure media services.**

You can concatenate `(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)` at the end of the URL, can play this url with any video player.

***Helpful posts***

[1. How to integrate Azure media player in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38344793/how-to-integrate-azure-media-player-in-android)

[2. How to run azure media player on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64269617/how-to-run-azure-media-player-on-android/64272669#64272669)

Comment: First post i already tried not working.Second post i tried run on webview seems running but i want it play in video player is that possible because need to send how long they watched mins or seconds details.

Comment: Tried using VideoPlayer not  working bro.Other normal videos working

Comment: @siva Maybe you can try to use `YoYo Video Player`.

Comment: @siva Very strange, I tested `video_player` and it just doesn't work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226861/discussion-between-siva-and-jason-pan).

Comment: @siva I also try it 3 hours, it doesn't work. I believe it's flutter's problem. You can open a issue on github for help.

Comment: @siva I hope my test results are useful to you. Please submit your questions in flutter's issues for official compatibility.

Comment: Sure Thanks for your help.I tried with web so far its working  fine

Comment: It's working in webview i have created one example project please go through if anyone need solution. https://github.com/sivabalan7811/Azure-media-player-in-flutter

Comment: @siva You embed html to realize this function, which is amazing.